# Import of large dataset in Neo4j taking really long (>12 hours) with Neo4j import tool

Tags: neo4j

I have a large dataset (about 1B nodes and a few billion relationships) that I am trying to import into Neo4j. I am using the Neo4j import tool. The nodes finished importing in an hour, however since then, the importer is stuck in a node index preparation phase (unless I am reading the output below incorrectly) for over 12 hours now.

...
Available memory:
  Free machine memory: 184.49 GB
  Max heap memory : 26.52 GB

Nodes
[>:23.39 MB/s---|PROPERTIE|NODE:|LAB|*v:37.18 MB/s---------------------------------------------]  1B
Done in 1h 7m 18s 54ms
Prepare node index
[*SORT:11.52 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------------------]881M
...

My question is how can I speed this up? I am thinking the following:
1. Split up the import command for nodes and relationships and do the nodes import.
2. Create indexes on the nodes
3. Do merge/match to get rid of dupes
4. Do rels import.

Will this help? Is there something else I should try? Is the heap size too large (I think not, but would like an opinion)?

Thanks.

**UPDATE** 
I also tried importing exactly half that data on the same machine and it gets stuck again in that phase at roughly the same amount of time (proportionally). So I have mostly eliminated disk space and memory as an issue. 
I have also checked my headers (since I noticed that other people ran into this problem when they had incorrect headers) and they seem correct to me. Any suggestions on what I else should be looking at?

**FURTHER UPDATE** 
Ok so now it is getting kind of ridiculous. I reduced my data size down to just one large file (about 3G). It only contains nodes of a single kind and only has ids. So the data looks something like this 
1|Author 
2|Author 
3|Author 

and the header (in a separate file) looks like this 
authorID:ID(Author)|:LABEL 

And my import still gets stuck in the sort phase. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong here. But I really have no clue what. Here is my command line to invoke this 
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j-import --into data/db/graph.db --id-type string --delimiter "|" \
--bad-tolerance 1000000000 --skip-duplicate-nodes true --stacktrace true --ignore-empty-strings true \
--nodes:Author "data/author/author_header_label.csv,data/author/author_half_label.csv.gz"

Most of the options for bad-tolerance and skip-duplicate-nodes are there to see if I can make it get through the import somehow at least once.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j is this?

Comment: It is the latest 2.3.1

Comment: I take that back. it is 2.2.5

Comment: Gah... it is 2.3 (Ent trial edition). The reason I got confused was I checked the README file and for some reason that says 2.2.5. Even though my installation was from here http://neo4j.com/artifact.php?name=neo4j-enterprise-2.3.0-unix.tar.gz

Comment: Can you see if there are many CPUs active at this point? Does it progress at all beyond 881M ? Could you get a thread dump and attach here at this point?

Comment: Which readme was htat?

Comment: I just now tried importing 1.7B nodes with the exact layout of `1|Author`,`2|Author`... data, split up into header and zipped data csv files. It worked fine:

`[*SORT:19,93 GB--------------------------------------------------------------------------------]  2B
`

i.e. confirmed to have gone beyond the point where yours get stuck. The import completed as it should and the `Prepare node index` stage took 20min.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I was using some the tips here <br/> [link](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets) where it says I can re-use the same csv file with different headers -- once for nodes and once for relationships. I underestimated the 1-n (ness) of the data I was using causing a lot of duplicates on the ID. That stage was basically almost all spent on trying to sort and then dedupe. Re-working my queries to extract the data split into nodes and rels files, fixed that problem. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: OK, great. Would you suggest any documentation changes to have other people avoid these problems?

Comment: Yes. A couple of things -- <br/>

Comment: Yes. In this doc http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets please specify that if you reuse the same file for nodes and relationships with different headers, be aware that there will be duplicate IDs that the importer needs to dedupe (which might take time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue. I was using some of the tips here 
 http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets where it says I can re-use the same csv file with different headers -- once for nodes and once for relationships. I underestimated the 1-n (ness) of the data I was using, causing a lot of duplicates on the ID. That stage was basically almost all spent on trying to sort and then dedupe. Re-working my queries to extract the data split into nodes and rels files, fixed that problem. Thanks for looking into this!

So basically, ideally always having separate files for each type of node and rel will give fastest results (at least in my tests).

Comment: This is a great comment. After reading it, I re-wrote my CSV files. The time to now import takes 1m20s. `IMPORT DONE in 1m 22s 172ms. 
Imported:
  1591048 nodes
  21449876 relationships
  71531032 properties
Peak memory usage: 1.048GiB
`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the batch importer I wrote for a stress test:

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-stress-test

I used both neo4j index and in memory map between two commit. It is really fast and works for both version of neo4j.

Ignore the tests and  get the batch importer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'll check it out. Meanwhile can you share some numbers on how much data you were able to load with this in what time? (I am asking because I'm in a bit of a time crunch and I want to make sure, the numbers at least make sense before I give it a go). Thanks again.

Comment: If you run the tests one of them will download a sample dataset and import it. I was able to import more than 3m of nodes in less than 15 minutes. But the time depends also on your test environment (cpu, ssd or magnetic disk, ram, etc)

Comment: Alessandro, that uses the Neo4j BatchInserter, right? Performance is OK, although scalability isn't. But if it's fast enough for the particular use case then it's absolutely an alternative.

Comment: Perfect let me know do that I can generalise it.

Comment: What do you mean about scalability?

Comment: Merely that the import tool has better scalability as the dataset to import approaches billions and beyond.